# How many integers between 1000 and 9999 inclusive consist of

Tags: permutations

How many integers between $1000$ and $9999$ inclusive consist of
 
(a) Distinct odd digits,
 
(b) Distinct digits,
 
(c) From the number of integers obtained in (b), how many are odd integers?

(a) ${}^5P_4 = 120$

(b) $9 \times 9 \times 8 \times 7 = 4536$

(c) I don't know how to find the odd integers in $4536$

Are the answers correct? Can you guys help solve me the (c)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you place $0,2,4,6,$ or $8$ in the units place, it becomes even. Hence, you will have to place $1,3,5,7,$ or $9$ in the units place to make it odd. So in the units place, you have $5$ choices.  In the thousand's place we have $8$ choices ($8$ because we have left out $0$ and the number in the units place). Similarly we have $8$ and $7$ choices in the hundreds and tens place, respectively . Hence, the answer should be $8\times 8 \times 7 \times 5 = 2240$.

Comment: oww...ok,.is my answer for A and B correct? Thanks

Comment: Yes they are .  is mine ?

Comment: @Tejus Yours is correct, verified on a computer (not that it was necessary!:)

Comment: Yeah i can understand your explanation..

Comment: Nice answer.  Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.